# How to make tshark to output valid pcap file used for other max GUI pcap viewer

Tags: pcap, tshark

```
 sudo tshark -i en0 -x -w icmp_sample.pcap
```

This command output a pcap file, but the it doesn't seem to be valid, Because CocoaPacket Analyzer can't open it

Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

If it's TShark 1.8 or later, by default, it does ***NOT*** output pcap files, it outputs [pcap-ng](http://www.winpcap.org/ntar/draft/PCAP-DumpFileFormat.html) files.

Libpcap 1.1.0 and later can read pcap-ng files, and OS X has had libpcap 1.1.x since Snow Leopard.  CocoaPacketAnalyzer links *statically* with its own version of libpcap - but a quick look at the strings in the program suggest that it's built with libpcap 1.1.0 or later.

However, it might, like Wireshark, use libpcap only for capturing network traffic, and have its own code to read capture files.  This means that, unlike programs that use libpcap to read capture files, it doesn't magically pick up the ability to read pcap-NG files if linked with a newer version of libpcap.

So, if you want to read captures with CocoaPacketAnalyzer (rather than Wireshark, which *can* read pcap-ng files, along with pcap files and a whole bunch of other types of files), you will have to have TShark write out pcap files by passing it the flag `-F pcap`, and you will have to convert any existing pcap-ng files that you want CocoaPacketAnalyzer to read into pcap files with `editcap -F pcap {input file} {output file}` or, on Snow Leopard and later, `tcpdump -r {input file} -w {output file}`.